# Grpc.Core.RpcException - Detail=failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I've been using GCP SecretManager in .Net core project ,while accessing one of the secret placed in GCP it throws an error

---

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unavailable",
> Detail="failed to connect to all addresses",
> DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException:
> {"created":"@1621849302.013000000","description":"Failed to pick
> subchannel","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":5397,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1621849296.458000000","description":"failed
> to connect to all
> addresses","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}")'

---

```
 public String AccessSecretVersion(string projectId = "strategic-ivy-310114", string secretId = "connectionString", string secretVersionId = "1")
    {
        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"C:\Learning\SampleApps\CosmosWithSecret\CosmosDBApp\CosmosDb_Demo_Crud\strategic-ivy-615459-a0f786577j32.json");
        // Create the client.
        SecretManagerServiceClient client = SecretManagerServiceClient.Create();

        // Build the resource name.
        SecretVersionName secretVersionName = new SecretVersionName(projectId, secretId, secretVersionId);

        // Call the API.
        AccessSecretVersionResponse result = client.AccessSecretVersion(secretVersionName);

        // Convert the payload to a string. Payloads are bytes by default.
        String payload = result.Payload.Data.ToStringUtf8();
        return payload;
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be an issue with grpc. From [this thread](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/23340), it appears the root cause could be related to a proxy. Are you using an http(s) proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I've also got this error.

I'm running the application on Windows, and what actually worked for me was to run it from WSL. For some reason it crashes on Windows.